# Can't access specific websites/applications (such as Skype)

Tags: macbook-pro, network, skype

I can't access specific websites/applications such as Skype or Slack on my Macbook Pro.

When I try to login into the Skype it just says "Connecting" and Slack doesn't connect to the server too (although I can reach Slack website). I also can't connect to Skype website (http://www.skype.com but I CAN reach http://community.skype.com).

I have tried:

- reinstalling Skype
- signing in and signing out
- reseting the router
- restarting my Macbook Pro
- deleting hosts folder
- disabling AVG AntiVirus
- flushing DNS cache

but nothing of these worked. I will be very grateful for any possible suggestions why this might be happening and how to solve it :)

**EDIT:** I am connected to WiFi at home, I am using corporate ISP provider (Telemach, it's one of the biggest ISP's here in Slovenia). OS version: MacOS Sierra version 10.12.4

**EDIT #2:** I've just tried connecting to Skype website over my smartphone which runs on Android and it's also not reaching the website, so I think is more a network-related problem.

**SOLVED:** My ISP had some problems.

Comment: Please add details about how (wired|wifi connection) and to what (ISP, corporate|education) this machine is connected.

Comment: @IconDaemon i have edited the post (using wifi connection) and corporate ISP if that's what you meant with ISP :)

Comment: Have you tried any of this in Safe Mode?

Comment: Yes I just tried in Safe Mode, it doesnt work.

Comment: I meant that perhaps if you were trying Skype at your business that your employer's firewall was blocking Skype traffic. Also, can other people connect to Skype on the same network, or are they blocked as well?

Comment: I assume that this wouldn't be possible since I tried to connect to http://www.skype.com with my smartphone that runs on Android. So i think it's more a network-related problem